# Rails Active Admin datetime input does not load the current date and time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

Is there any option for formtastic in Active Admin, for the showing current datetime in datetime input. It's coming with blank on the form load.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to do this. However there are multiple options to do this

1- if you want to go with default feature provided by formtastic(drop down type time selection) then in the model class:

```
def after_initialize
  self.start_time ||= Time.now
end
```

Then when the form is displayed, it will already have the time populated and set correctly.

2- if you want to just show date then you can use

```
f.input :start_time, :as => :datepicker, :html_option => { value: Time.now }
```

3- use https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_datetimepicker gem